# How can I make a Racket reader macro to transform any instance of one character into two other characters?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

More specifically, I need any instance of `|` to be transformed into `\|`. I tried reading the documentation on reader macros and I am extremely lost. Can somebody explain this in understandable terms, or ideally show me how to write such a macro.

Comment: Question: can you explain more why do you need this?

Comment: Here's potentially relevant documentation on readtables: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-reader.html#(part._readtable)  to extend the reader.  However, if we can hear more about the particular purpose for the transformation you're thinking of, maybe there's something better one can do here.

Comment: @dyoo I really really really want to make a function called `|`. I actually ran into that page before, but I will take a closer look. If I figure it out, I will post the answer here and let you know.

Comment: Following up: why do you want a function called `|`?  That seems somewhat weird without more context.  Can you say more why you want this?  You _can_ do it without reader macros, using escapes like this: `(define (\| x) (list "pipe" x))`.

Comment: @dyoo yes, I am going to have the function be called `\|`, but I read in code with `(read)` and then evaluate it. The code I am reading in really needs to be able to call a function like `(| blah blah)` which I will then translate into `(\| blah blah)`.

Comment: @dyoo Ah, looks like your link answered my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially destroying the usual meaning of `|` in the usual syntax, so you should really do that in some uniform way to minimize surprises.  Your solution doesn't do that -- it treats `|` differently based on whether it's the first thing or not, and that's bad.  For example, `xxx|xxx` reads it as a character in the whole symbol which means that you get a symbol with a name of `"xxx|xxx"`, but with an input of `|xxx` you get two symbols, with names of `"|"` and `"xxx"` respectively.  It's therefore better to just make your syntax treat `|` as other characters to get a more consistent and easier-to-explain behavior.

Another possible problem with your code is your use of `#f` as a readtable, which means that the reader is not going to compose with a reader that is potentially modified.

And finally, you should really pay attention to the extra arguments and return a syntax object when they're given.  The reason for that is obvious, and my guess is that your reason for not doing so is that you're interested in just reading such code.  But you should really have one eye looking at potential extensions, and in Racket, and obvious future for such code would be to make up a proper language instead of a read+eval hack.  It's true that it might seem like an overkill, but in this case there is a simple solution of using the "same as this other character" shortcut to avoid writing lengthy code.

The following addresses all of these:

```
(define rt (let ([c (current-readtable)]) (make-readtable c #\| #\a c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Here is the code to adjust the `(read)` function to change all instances of `|` into `\|`:

```
(define rt2 (make-readtable #f #\| 'non-terminating-macro
                            (lambda (c in . _)
                              '\|)))

(parameterize ([current-readtable rt2]
               [current-namespace ns])
  (eval (read)))
```